# Can I run 24 V DC fan with on 18 V DC?

Tags: power, dc, fan

I have got a coffee machine which had its cooling fan died. The current fan is 18 V DC but the only replacement fans I can find are 24 V DC. Will that be a issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: You really need to know some details of the fan to know what to replace it with. If there any info that tells you the current rating, rpm and CFM of the fan?

Comment: Doesnt display RPM. Just following Model number : 5010s18h , DC 18v 0.12A

Comment: Then you could look on Digikey, I found this DELTA fan rated at 13.5V but the operating range is up to 16V: https://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/EFB0512VHBBBN.pdf  You could put a small regulator in with the fan and or simply put a diode in series with the fan supply.

Comment: The fan will probably run. But  it is very difficult to say whether it  will provide enough airflow. Do you know the airflow or power rating of the original fan that failed? If so, add it to your question by editing it (don't answer here in the comment section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer 12V fan can be powered by 5V just fine. It will still work at a low speed but sufficient to actually cool and it will be significantly more silent. I use this very often and it suffices for many applications.

Going from 24V to 18V is like going from 12 to 9, so it will definitely work at a sufficient speed to be good in most scenarios.

If you do not actually have overheating problems with the device you try to cool-down you can certainly use it at 18V.

18V fans are indeed more rare, but should not be too difficult to find if it's not a special design. General use fans can definitely be [found](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TX9025L18S-DC-18V-0-14A-9CM-9025-refrigerator-thermostat-cabinet-cooling-fan-high-quality/32816730712.html).

I would not recommend using a 12V one because it may just fry.

I you want to use a 12V one, get a [step-down circuit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-DC-24V-18V-to-12V-3A-Step-Down-Module-MINI-Buck-Converter-Power-Supply-Circuit/32778770850.html) from 18 to 12V.

Answer (score -1):

The cooling fan will run slower, which may or may not cause something overheat.

Comment: Other option i see is getting a 12v DC fan. Do i need to reduce the volts or will it handle the extra 6volts ?

Comment: The fan may run faster,  and die in very short order. What's wrong with getting the correct 18v fan? If you supply a 12v fan with 12v, is that fan going to deliver as much air as the original did, or will it allow the machine to overheat?

Comment: I cannot find the replacement 12v fan :(

Comment: I would run an 24V fan on 18V before running a 12V fan on 18V. You are liable to burn out a 12V fan on 18V since it will try to draw more than double the current